# comparing gchar to a string

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm using the following code to compare a string store in a `gchar` to a `char` array read from a file:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, config) != NULL)
  {
    printf("line content is %s",line+5);
    printf("size of comparison: %i\n",g_utf8_strlen(active_selection,-1));
    if (g_ascii_strncasecmp(line+5,active_selection,g_utf8_strlen(active_selection,-1)+1)==1)
    {
      printf("success \n\n");
    }
    else
      printf("failure\n");
  }
```

the config file values are:

```
set "hello"
button "hello" "some text"
button "phone" "more text"
set "pmrs"
button "test" "test even more text"
```

`printf()` shows the following values:

> `line+5` = hello"
>   `line+5` (second iteration) = on "hello"
>   `active_selection` = hello
>   `g_utf8_strlen(active_selection,-1)` = 5

What I was expecting was that the first iteration (`hello"`) would return `true`
and the second would return `false` (on `"hello"`),
thinking only the first 5 characters would be compared.

Apparently that is not the case since I always get the `else` statement executed (I used `printf` to test).

Comment: What first iteration? What second iteration? Your code does not show any iterations. Please post the exact code that you are referring to as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have modified the original post with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All string compare functions return `0` on match. So your `if` conditional should check for `0` not `1`.

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-ascii-strncasecmp:

> Returns
>
> 0 if the strings match, a negative value if s1 < s2 , or a positive
>   value if s1 > s2 .

Comment: DUH, I feel so stupid
thanks this has been driving me crazy